# trying to connect typeorm to mysql container in docker-compose but got this error Error: Access denied for user ''@'172.29.0.3' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am running node and mysql containers with docker compose and try to connect typeorm with mysql container but I got the same error over and over

**this my docker-compose file**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_NAME: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

**this is my typeorm config file**

```
import {DataSource} from 'typeorm';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export const appDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    entities:[
        'src/entities/*.js'
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true
});
```

**and this is my .env file**

```
MYSQL_USER = root
MYSQL_PASSWORD = password 
MYSQL_NAME = test
MYSQL_HOST = db
MYSQL_PASSWORD = password
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL and application container seems to be in two different networks.

Try with following `docker-compose` :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_NAME: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

here both containers will run on host.

For fixing : > Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Try adding following to `/etc/hosts` file. (If you are on Linux destro)

```
0.0.0.0 db
0.0.0.0 app
```

Comment: I used it and it gave me this error Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN db